# Trying to run a Coffee shop code in python, isn't working

Tags: python, dictionary

```python
prices=[120,130,120,150]

menu = {
    1: ["Latte", 120],
    2: ["Capputino", 130],
    3: ["Americano", 120],
    4: ["Espresso",150]
}

headers = ["No.", 'Name', "Price"]
print(f'{headers[0]: <10}{headers[1]: <15}{headers[2]}')

for value, key in menu.items():
    print(f'{value: <10}{key[0]: <15}{key[1]}')

myorder_coffee=[]
myorder_cost=[]
total=0

print("Welcome to COFFEE & DELIGHT")

name=input("Enter your name: ")
order=input("Enter the name of your order: ")
quantity=input("Enter the amount of drinks.you want to order: ")

if order=="Latte":
    myorder_coffee.append(coffee[0])
    myorder_cost.append(prices[0])
    total=quantity*120
    print(name,"ordered",quantity,"Latte")
    print("Total amount to be paid=",total)
elif order=="Capputino":
    myorder_coffee.append(coffee[1])
    myorder_cost.append(prices[1])
    total=quantity*130
    print(name,"ordered",quantity,"Capputino")
    print("Total amount to be paid=",total)
elif order=="Americano":
    myorder_coffee.append(coffee[2])
    myorder_cost.append(prices[2])
    total=quantity*120
    print(name,"ordered",quantity,"Americano")
    print("Total amount to be paid=",total)
elif order=="Espresso":
    myorder_coffee.append(coffee[3])
    myorder_cost.append(prices[3])
    total=quantity*150
    print(name,"ordered",quantity,"Espresso")
    print("Total amount to be paid=",total)
else:
    print("Item not in menu")
```

Well i totally wasn't expecting this to happen.

```
No.       Name           Price
1         Latte          120
2         Capputino      130
3         Americano      120
4         Espresso       150
Welcome to COFFEE & DELIGHT
Enter your name: pp
Enter the name of your order: Americano
Enter the amount of drinks. you want to order: 4
pp ordered 4 Americano
Total amount to be paid= 444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444

[Program finished]]
```

[Link to screengrab of above program run.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Mfyy.jpg)

Comment: Please look at the [how to ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as well as [write a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The current post is incorrectly formatted and is missing some variable declarations.

Comment: You forgot to convert ```quantity``` into an integer, instead it is a string. In effect turning ```total``` into 120 '4's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
quantity=input("Enter the amount of drinks.you want to order: ")
```

`input()` returns a string.  So `quantity` is a string.

```
total=quantity*120
```

When you multiply a string by an integer, you get repeated copies of the string.  So you got the string "4", repeated 120 times.

If you want integer input, use `int()`:

```
quantity=int(input("Enter the amount of drinks.you want to order: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
prices = [120, 130, 120, 150]

menu = {
    1: ["Latte", 120],
    2: ["Capputino", 130],
    3: ["Americano", 120],
    4: ["Espresso", 150]
}

headers = ["No.", 'Name', "Price"]
print(f'{headers[0]:<10}{headers[1]:<15}{headers[2]}')

for key, value in menu.items():
    print(f'{key:<10}{value[0]:<15}{value[1]}')

myorder_coffee = []
myorder_cost = []
total = 0

print("Welcome to COFFEE & DELIGHT")

name = input("Enter your name: ")
order = input("Enter the name of your order: ")
quantity = int(input("Enter the amount of drinks you want to order: "))

for key, value in menu.items():
    if order == value[0]:
        myorder_coffee.append(value[0])
        myorder_cost.append(prices[key-1])
        total = quantity * prices[key-1]
        print(name, "ordered", quantity, value[0])
        print("Total amount to be paid=", total)
        break
else:
    print("Item not in menu")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```